# is there a way to define entities by symlink in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I have an API platform project. I want to retreive my entities from another project entities(symfony project). Is there a way to define the path to the other project entities without creating a bundle or sub folder. My api project should use my other project entities.

I made my api entity folder a symlink of my other project but the symlinks are ignored.

Comment: that's weird... where I work, we have project where every bundle folder is a symlink of another project

Comment: for me it's not a bundle, just entity folder

Comment: The docs might help: [Doctrine Mapping Configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#mapping-configuration) There are also quite a few examples on sof.  If your api platform is based on the Symfony framework then look in the Doctrine documentation configuration section.

Comment: it's weird I agree, what you could do is creating a composer library(type of directory) and pointing it on both projects

Comment: You could serialize this entities and send to your API.